# not a moment too soon - is it fast or slow?

Tags: idioms, expressions

Is this *late* or *early*? It's a bit unclear to me.

Because this question body wasn't meeting good quality standards of this site, I had to write this additional sentence.

Comment: It's neither fast nor slow- it's just in time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Not a moment too soon** [implies](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/not-a-moment-too-soon) that something happened when it was almost too late; **just in time**

> Help arrived - and not a moment too soon.
>
> Another minute and he'd have drowned; she found him in the pool not a moment too soon.

With this idiom, the five words are usually kept together. One may say

> She arrived *not a moment too soon*.

But [**not**](http://books.google.com/books?id=FDVIxLznBy8C&pg=PA70&lpg=PA70&dq=idiom+%22not+a+moment+too+soon%22&source=bl&ots=DQ9dnflZG6&sig=BMgzPDy2Q7x-AdvQZQQxoqdxsck&hl=en&sa=X&ei=cea4UsDlGsTlsAT0wIFA&ved=0CGEQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=idiom%20%22not%20a%20moment%20too%20soon%22&f=false) (if using the idiom as intended)

> She did *not* arrive *a moment too soon*. (incorrect)

Picky, I know, but it's idiomatic usage.

Answer (score 0):

It is an idiom, and it is not helpful to try to analyse its literal meaning. The literal meaning is a sort of [litotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litotes), where "not too soon" means "almost too late".